# AsyncTask.cancel() not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I just confused and don't know what to do anymore. I want to execute an AsyncTask, and cancel it when i press back button, home button or whatever that make the activity paused.

I have already add [isCancelled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled()). I called [cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)) from Activity's onPause(). I instantiate and execute my Asynctask from onCreate.

The funny thing is, isCancelled() is never true. Always false.

Below is my AsyncTack, am I missing something ?

```
private class Check extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, StatusToReturn> {
    Reservasi r;
    private boolean  forceCancel = false;

    public Check(Reservasi r) {
        this.r = r;
    }



    public synchronized boolean isForceCancel() {
        return forceCancel;
    }



    public synchronized void setForceCancel(boolean forceCancel) {
        this.forceCancel = forceCancel;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(StatusToReturn result) {
        //blablabla...
    }

    @Override
    protected StatusToReturn doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        StatusToReturn sssss;
        StatusToReturn ddddd;
        while (true) {
            if (isCancelled() || isForceCancel()) {
                sssss = new StatusToReturn("Waw");
                break;
            }

                            /*SOME LITTLE NETWORKS THING HERE*/

                            //Yes, i want a sleep.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sssss;
    }
}
```

oh, i added that "forceCancel" , desperately trying to cancel it by making it true from onPause(). Its value is always false when i debugged it.

I am using Acer Z120, Android 4.1.1 for testing and debugging, if someone wondering.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this code snippet

```
@Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(CLASSOBJECT!= null && CLASSOBJECT.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING) {
            CLASSOBJECT.cancel(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but, I tried it, debug it, but isCancelled still return false.

Comment: try to get the status after cancelling the AsyncTask like this `CLASSOBJECT.getStatus()` it'll return `canceled`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, it is very helpful. I found the problem following your lead. I executed the CLASSOBJECT two times, in onCreate and onResume. I deleted the one in onCreate.

Comment: @MarchellImanuel `CLASSOBJECT=YOU ASYNCTASK CLASS's OBJECT` if answer proves to be useful to you then accept it so others can gain knowledge from it.

Comment: Accepted. :) yes, i understood what CLASSOBJECT means.